# Python scripts parametrization

Tags: java, python, properties

In Java, I can use `.properties` file for specifying some program parameters (like data files location).

What correspondent concept is used in Python? (If it's version-dependent, I'm interested in a solution for Python 2.5).

Comment: A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9736769/118520)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're interested in the ConfigParser package. It has the advantage of being part of the standard library which means it cross-platform, and available everywhere.

http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you are looking for the same discussed here.

[Properties file in python (similar to Java Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595363/properties-file-in-python-similar-to-java-properties)